# Como ordenar um data.frame por colunas no R?

Tags: r, data.frame, order

Suponha um data.frame com valores numéricos e strings:

```
 set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(w=rep(c("A", "B"), 2), x= rep(c("D", "C"), 2), y= rnorm(4), z=rnorm(4),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dados
 w x          y          z
1 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
2 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
3 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
4 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
```

Como faço para ordenar o data.frame por uma coluna? E como faço para ordenar com mais de uma coluna, e cada uma com ordens diferentes (algumas em ordem crescente, outras em ordem decrescente)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da para fazer isso direto no `order`, basta informar multiplos parâmetros.

```
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(w=rep(c("A", "B"), 2), x= rep(c("D", "C"), 2), y= rnorm(4), z=rnorm(4),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dados[order(dados$w, dados$x, dados$y, decreasing=c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), ] # No caso, ordena de acordo por w em ordem alfabética inversa, x em ordem alfabética e y em ordem decrescente. Se quiser que tudo seja na mesma ordem, basta um TRUE ou FALSE, que valerá para todos.

  w x          y          z
4 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
2 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
1 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
3 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
```

Comment: Para você ver como sempre dá para aprender mesmo em coisas simples, não sabia que o `decreasing` aceitava vetores!

Answer (score 8):

Pode também utilizar o pacote `plyr` para a ordenação.

```
library(plyr)
arrange(dados,desc(z))
  w x          y          z
1 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
2 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
3 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
4 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
```

O arrange também funciona para texto sem precisar da função auxiliar `xtfrm`

```
arrange(dados,desc(w),z)
  w x          y          z
1 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
2 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
3 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
4 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
```

Outra opção interessante é usar o pacote sqldf. O default de sql é ordem ascendente.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT w,x,y,z 
      FROM dados
      Order BY x, desc y")
  w x          y          z
1 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
2 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
3 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
4 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a função `order`. Para ordenar o data.frame pela coluna `z` em ordem decrescente, por exemplo:

```
dados[order(dados$z, decreasing=TRUE),]
  w x          y          z
4 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
3 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
1 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
2 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
```

Para ordenar de maneira diferente para cada coluna, há dois pontos a serem observados. Se as colunas forem numéricas, você pode colocar um menos antes do vetor para inverter a direção desta coluna, por exemplo, `order(dados$z, -dados$y, decreasing=TRUE)` organiza de ordem decrescente em z e depois em ordem crescente em y (que neste caso não faz diferença pois não há empates em z).

Já com colunas de caracteres é preciso utilizar uma função auxiliar `xtfrm`. Por exemplo, para ordenar os dados de forma "decrescente" (alfabeticamente) no vetor `w` e, após, crescente no vetor `z`:

```
dados[order(-xtfrm(dados$w), dados$z),]
  w x          y          z
2 B C  0.1836433 -0.8204684
4 B C  1.5952808  0.7383247
1 A D -0.6264538  0.3295078
3 A D -0.8356286  0.4874291
```