# Como ordenar todas as colunas em ordem decrescente e conjuntamente?

Tags: r, order

Fiz uma tabela dinâmica no R resumidamente com os seguintes dados:

```
Dados
  A B C    
  0 2 1  
  4 6 2  
  2 3 4
```

Gostaria de reordenar todas as colunas ao mesmo tempo e em ordem decrescente para ficar assim:

```
  A B C    
  4 6 4  
  2 3 2  
  0 2 1
```

Em outra [pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6123/como-ordenar-um-data-frame-por-colunas-no-r) no fórum, sugeriram esse código:

```
df[order(df$A, df$B, df$C, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Todavia, esse código retornou somente a primeira coluna em ordem decrescente. Fiz alguma coisa errada? Tem outra forma de fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar `apply` para aplicar `sort`em cada coluna:

```
dados <- data.frame(A = c(0,4,2), B = c(2,6,3), C = c(1,2,4))

dados2 <- as.data.frame(apply(dt, 2, sort, decreasing = TRUE))
# OU
dados2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(dt, sort, decreasing = TRUE))

dados2
#>   A B C
#> 1 4 6 4
#> 2 2 3 2
#> 3 0 2 1
```

Mas como apontado na [resposta de Paulo Marques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/578127/117168), *data.frames* pressupõem que cada linha corresponde a um indivíduo, então veja se isso faz sentido para os seus dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado! O comando que vc propôs resolveu meu problema. São 96 colunas que eu precisava ordenar e analisar dessa forma.  Para o meu propósito faz sim sentido.

Answer (score 5):

Dataframes são geralmente utilizados para armazenar dados onde cada `LINHA` é uma **observação** e cada `COLUNA` contém uma das medidas.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
Nome    Peso_Kg   Altura_cm
Joao      90         175
Pedro     80         180
```

Caso façamos a ordenação conforme o que foi solicitado na pergunta para **todas** as coluna, teremos:

```
Nome    Peso_Kg   Altura_cm
Pedro      90        180
Joao       80        175
```

Ou seja, os dados deste dataframe não fazem mais sentido frente ao que foi coletado.

**ENTRETANTO**, caso isso faça sentido para seus dados, e queira ordenar cada coluna independente da outra. Veja abaixo a solução

```
df <- as.data.frame(list(A=c(0,4,2), B=c(2,6,3), C=c(1,2,4)))

for (col in names(df)) {
    df[[col]] <- sort(df[[col]], decreasing = TRUE)
}
```

Resultado

```
df

  A B C
1 4 6 4
2 2 3 2
3 0 2 1
```